# Uniqueness of mesurable function composition

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $h$ be a
$\left( \Omega\mathcal{,F} \right) \rightarrow \left( S,\mathcal{E} \right)$
measurable function, and $g$ be a
$\left( \Omega\mathcal{,F} \right) \rightarrow \left( \mathbb{R,}\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) \right)$
measurable function, where $\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ is the
Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. How do we prove there exists an
almost surely unique
$\left( \mathbb{R,}\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) \right) \rightarrow \left( \mathbb{R,}\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) \right)$
measurable function $f$ s.t. $f \circ g = h$?

Comment: What makes you think this is true?

Comment: Are you sure this is always possible? What if $g=0$ but $h$ is injective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is horribly false.  For instance, if $g$ is constant, then $f\circ g$ is constant for any $f$, so such an $f$ cannot exist unless $h$ is constant.  Moreover, even when $h$ is constant, $f$ will not be unique (up to sets of measure $0$) since only the value of $f$ at the constant value of $g$ matters.